# Django django-adminfiles

Tags: django, image, file, admin, blogs

I'm creating a Blog with Django and I need to insert images on the posts. As far as I know, the best package for that is [django-adminfiles](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-adminfiles/overview)

The installation guide is pretty simple but I don't understand the 3rd step(because of my bad English level :S):

> Make the contents of the adminfiles/static/adminfiles directory available at STATIC_URL/adminfiles. This can be done by through your webserver configuration, via an app such as django.contrib.staticfiles, or by copying the files or making a symlink.

I have run collecstatic, copy the files of adminfiles/static/adminfiles to my static directory and nothing seems to work. When I write a post, it should appear like in this [video](http://vimeo.com/8940852) but the image thumbmails and "All uploads images","Upload","Refresh".... doesn't appear.
I'm pretty new to Django and I'm a bit lost with this silly question. ¿Does someone know what i have to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### My environment

- OS: CentOS7_x86_64
- Python: 2.7.5 (must be devel version)
- Django: 1.8.1

### Step

1. Install

   - *'adminfiles'* :
     `pip install django-adminfiles==1.0.1`
   - *'sorl-thumbnail'* :
     `pip install sorl-thumbnail==12.2`
   - *Prerequisites for 'pillow'* :
     `yum install libtiff-devel libjpeg-devel libzip-devel freetype-devel lcms2-devel libwebp-devel tcl-devel tk-devel -y`
   - *'pillow'* :
     `pip install pillow==2.8.1`
2. Use adminfiles

   I have created a django project named 'demo', it has only one app 'trial'.

   ```
        demo
          |
          |------ demo
          |        |---- __init__.py
          |        |---- settings.py
          |        |---- urls.py
          |        |---- wsgi.py
          |
          |------ manage.py
          |------ trial
                    |---- \aa___init__.py
                    |---- admin.py
                    |---- models.py
                    |---- tests.py
                    |---- views.py
   ```

   To use adminfiles in the 'demo' project we must do the following:

   - Add 'adminfiles', 'sorl.thumbnail' to INSTALLED_APPS tuple of demo/settings.py file.

     ```
     INSTALLED_APPS = (
         'django.contrib.admin',
         'django.contrib.auth',
         'django.contrib.contenttypes',
         'django.contrib.sessions',
         'django.contrib.messages',
         'django.contrib.staticfiles',
         'adminfiles',
         'sorl.thumbnail',
         'trial',
     )
     ```
   - Add adminfiles url to the urlatterns list of demo/urls.py file.

     ```
     urlpatterns = [
         url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
         url(r'^adminfiles/', include('adminfiles.urls')),
     ]
     ```
   - Modify admin of trial/admin.py file.

     (Note: Article is a model defined in trial/models.py, it has a TextField field named 'text')

     ```
     from django.contrib import admin
     from models import Article

     from adminfiles.admin import FilePickerAdmin

     admin.site.register(Article)

     class ExtraAdmin(FilePickerAdmin):
        adminfiles_fields = ('text',)

     admin.site.register(Article, ExtraAdmin)
     ```
   - python manage.py migrate
   - Set MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT.

     demo/settings.py :

     ```
     MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
     MEDIA_ROOT = '/data/media/'
     ```

     demo/urls.py :

     ```
     from django.conf import settings
     from django.conf.urls.static import static

     urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
       url(r'^adminfiles/', include('adminfiles.urls')),
     ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
     ```

     After the above settings, the upload files will be stored in '/data/media/adminfiles/' dir.