# Good way to upload and browse uploaded file

Tags: python, django

I want to make a upload/browse file in admin Django to upload and insert some images in editor of admin Django. I know some choice as `Django-filebrowser, Django-adminfiles`.

*Django-filebrowser*: if I use this pack, I have to install Grapelli has problem vs auto slug (although native theme of Django work perfectly, I dont understand why)

*Django-adminfiles*: it does not work at all, It show error `'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'has_key' Django` when I try to upload a file.

Both of them do not work for me. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

look at this answer：[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30223614/4037409)，it gives the use steps of django-adminfiles.

Hope it helps you out！