# Storing several images in article in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I create a Django app which has articles, currently stored as html in a text-field in the model. In template I show them using `{{article.text|safe }}`.

But I need to be able to put images in any place of acrticle: different quantity to each article or none to some of them.

I see following options to do that:

1. **To store html-text including `<img src='...'>` in database** (and loose the opportunity to use django staticfiles in this case?)...
2. **To create ImageField (or several) in model** - in this case I will have limited fixed number of images for each article and new questions - how to put images inside html-content (not above or below).
3. **To store prepared articles htmls with images as staticfiles** - get problems with access and loose the ability to edit content rapidly using django admin panel (ex. to fix a typo).
4. **To use WYSIWYG-editor with possibility to upload images in django admin.** This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362875/django-django-adminfiles) tells about django-adminfiles but it was last updated in 2013 and doesn't work in Django 1.9 and later (I use 1.11). Even if find a modern plugin like that - main problem is that content is currently beeing prepared by other people having no access to admin panel in plain text files and I use a script to parse it and import to DB on weekly basis.

Please, help me with a choise or maybe there is some best practise I didn't find out.

**Update:** Looking for different WYSIWYG-editors I found this: [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) and liked it a lot. At the moment I think it's a solution, the only sad thing is that I have to create new field in the model like this:

```
content = RichTextUploadingField(_("CKeditor test"), null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below plugin for upload images from editor

https://github.com/avelino/django-wysiwyg-redactor

```
html_text = RedactorField(
        verbose_name=u'HTML Text',
        redactor_options={'lang': 'en', 'focus': 'true'},
        upload_to='images/'
    )
```

Comment: Dont't like it due to several reasons: not updated since 2013, "Starting with version 7.6.2 redactor-js is licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 license. For commercial use please buy license here: http://redactorjs.com/download/ or use earlier version."